# Multer: Unexpected end of form

Tags: node.js, express, multer

Currently unable to get a basic multer text form example working.

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = 8077;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.info(`Started http://localhost:${PORT} (PID: ${process.pid})`);
  const multer = require('multer');
  const upload = multer();
  app.post('/post', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
    console.log("POST");
    console.log(req.body);
  });
  postSomething();
});

async function postSomething() {
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  let res = await fetch('http://localhost:8077/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=abcde12345' },
    body: `--abcde12345
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="id"
Content-Type: text/plain
foo
--abcde12345--`
  });
  console.log(res.status);
}
```

What is the problem with parsing this body?

```
Error: Unexpected end of form
    at Multipart._final (C:\projects\bar\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:588:17)
    at callFinal (node:internal/streams/writable:696:27)
    at prefinish (node:internal/streams/writable:725:7)
    at finishMaybe (node:internal/streams/writable:735:5)
    at Multipart.Writable.end (node:internal/streams/writable:633:5)
    at IncomingMessage.onend (node:internal/streams/readable:693:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `\r\n` instead of implicit line endings as well as ensuring that there is an empty line before each value.

```js
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const PORT = 8077;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.info(`Started http://localhost:${PORT} (PID: ${process.pid})`);
  const multer = require('multer');
  const upload = multer();
  app.post('/post', upload.none(), (req, res) => {
    console.log("POST");
    console.log(req.body?.id);
  });
  postSomething();
});

async function postSomething() {
  const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  let res = await fetch('http://localhost:8077/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=abcde12345' },
    body: `--abcde12345\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="id"\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nfoo\r\n--abcde12345--`
  });
  console.log(res.status);
}
```

So basically my mistakes were:

- Not using CRLF
- Forgetting a newline before `foo`
- Using the wrong boundary (the header has one `--` less than the body)

Answer (score -1):

use body-parser middleware for this issue and will resolve your problem

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// ...
app.use(bodyParser())
```

Comment: Nope, same error. IMO, multer is responsible for parsing.

Comment: your code is not in the right format. What you are trying to achieve can you explain further also these middlerware required in older version nodays without these kind of middlerwares we can send our request

Comment: The code runs fine. I am posting a field `id` with value `foo` and I expect it to be in `req.body.id`. I am unable to parse the request - run the code in NodeJS v16 and you will see the error.

Comment: for id requesting we use req.params.id not req.body.id. Kindly update this and try agin

Comment: Sorry, you don't know what you're talking about. `params` refers to Route Params in the path. This is a POST body.